# How to get values from a json file efficiently with python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to retrieve values from different layers of a json file, I'm using a quite silly way -- get the values from one dictionary inside another dictionary through for looping. I want to get all the "title" and "question" and put them in a list or a pandas dataframe.  How can I retrieve the values needed in a simpler way? How to handle json files efficiently in general?
Thanks a lot for anyone who answers the question:)

here's a piece of the json:

```
{
    "contact": "xxx",
    "version": 1.0,
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "anges-musiciens-(national-gallery)",
            "paragraphs": [
                {
                    "qas": [
                        {
                            "answers": [{
                                    "text": "La Vierge aux rochers"
                                }
                            ],
                            
                            "question": "Que concerne principalement les documents ?"
                        }
                 }
             ]
        }
     ]
}
```

```
titles = []
questions = []

for i in data["data"]:
    titles.append(i["title"])

    for p in i["paragraphs"]:
        for q in p["qas"]:
            questions.append(q["question"])
    
print(titles)
print(questions)
```

Comment: Paste the json as text, not an image, so we can copy it. But [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) is very quick

Comment: I see no issue with this code. Although, you may want to keep the titles still associated with the questions. In which case I would do: `{i["title"]: [q["question"] for p in i["paragraphs"] for q in p["qas"]] for i in data["data"]}`

Comment: Take a look at `pandas.json_normalize()` if you want to turn it into a dataframe.

Comment: Your json is still not correct: `SyntaxError: closing parenthesis '}' does not match opening parenthesis '['`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure is regular (i.e. always the same hierarchy patterns and no missing keys when a dictionary is present), then you can obtain your results with nested list comprehensions:

```
titles    = [d["title"] for d in data["data"]]
questions = [q["question"] for d in data.get("data",[])
                           for p in d.get("paragraphs",[])
                           for q in p.get("qas",[])]
```

If the structure is not regular, you will need to keep track of new entries as you progress deeper and deeper in the structure.  You can do this with a list (or a queue):

```
titles    = []
questions = []
more      = [*data.items()]  # start with key/values of first level dictionary
while more:
    key,value = more.pop(0)            # get next key/value pair to process
    if isinstance(value,list):         # if value is a list
        more.extend(enumerate(value))  # add key/values using indexes as keys
    elif isinstance(value,dict):       # if value is a dictionary
        more.extend(value.items())     # add more key/values from its items
    elif key == "title":               # for "title" key, add to titles list
        titles.append(value)
    elif key == "question":            # same for "question" keys
        questions.append(value)
```

output:

```
print(titles)
['anges-musiciens-(national-gallery)']

print(questions)

['Que concerne principalement les documents ?']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a DataFrame

```
data = {
    "contact": "xxx",
    "version": 1.0,
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "anges-musiciens-(national-gallery)",
            "paragraphs": [
                {
                    "qas": [
                        {
                            "answers": [{
                                    "text": "La Vierge aux rochers"
                                }
                            ],
                            
                            "question": "Que concerne principalement les documents ?"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'], ['paragraphs', 'qas'], 'title')[['title', 'question']]
print(df)

                                title                            question  
0  anges-musiciens-(national-gallery)  Que concerne principalement les documents ?
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion to perform a depth-first-search on the nested structure:

```py
def extract_fields(json_data, fields_of_interest=None, extracted=None):
    if extracted is None:
        extracted = {}
    if isinstance(json_data, dict):
        for field,value in json_data.items():
            if field in fields_of_interest:
                extracted.setdefault(field, []).append(value)
            elif isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, list):
                extract_fields(value, fields_of_interest, extracted)
    elif isinstance(json_data, list):
        for x in json_data:
            extract_fields(x, fields_of_interest, extracted)
    return extracted

j = {'title': 'abc',
     'deep': {'question': 'zyx',
              'deeper': [{'title': 'def',
                          'question': 'wvu',
                          'nothing': 'hahaha'},
                         {'even deeper': [{'title': 'ghi',
                                           'question':'tsr',
                                           'answer': 42},
                                          {'not a title': "ceci n'est pas une pipe"}]}]}}

extracted = extract_fields(j, ('title', 'question'))

print(extracted)
# {'title': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 'question': ['zyx', 'wvu', 'tsr']}
```